# Trying to setup centre channel using two sound cards in Ubuntu Studio, need help

Tags: sound, equalizer

I am hoping someone can help me out :

**Version of Ubuntu** : Ubuntu Studio

**Summary of goal** : I want to use a centre speaker as a dialogue speaker,along with two floor standing speakers, routing the sound through two sound cards. One handling the left and right channel and one handling just the centre speaker.

I have managed to get both sound cards to work simultaneously using **paprefs**
but I would like to apply a filter to the centre channel(2nd sound card), so i can filter out the lows and the highs, Only on one sound card.

I have tried PulseEffects but that applies the filter to both sound cards.

I would also like to reroute both Left and Right channels through software and output to the second sound card in mono,at the moment i am using a splitter cable to take both left and right and input it in to the centre channel amplifier.

**Summary of request**

**1) apply a EQ or a filter to only one sound card in a two sound card system.**

**2) have one of those soundcards output in mono.**

If anyone has a better solution to what I presume would be a 3.1 sound setup, I would happily do that. Or if Ubuntu Studio is the wrong platform to attempt this, i would also be happy to install an other distro, if there is a better suited one. I went with Ubuntu studio just for audio output quality.

Thank you in advance, if you need any more information, i would be delighted to provide. Both sound cards are on USB (ones a Ibasso DAC, and the other some cheap generic USB dongle).

A

Comment: Using two sound cards because the dac my primary sound card only outputs in stereo and i had the other one in a drawer. So I figured it would be possible to do this with the equipment i had. I found an article about paprefs so i figured i could get things going from there.I also had the centre speaker from a previous surround setup but the receiver packed in. If it would be easier to just buy a cheap surround sound card i could do that.

Comment: Version of ubuntu, thank you for the reply. 

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

Comment: I'm not sure how you would even set something like this up even if your sound card had more channels. 3 channel and 3.1 channel audio is extremely uncommon. A lot would also depend on how the speakers are actually connected.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, For family use >200 Watt speakers. I have tried several cheap DACs. They do an excellent job on the Digital output channels, co-axial or optical. 1. Get the high-quality USB DAC. 2. Connect a high-quality AV amplifier. 3. Use good player such as Audacious which directly connects to DAC and operates. Let AV amp equalizes the centre speaker (you don't need, probably). But these are nothing like a professional PA mixer. #1 and #2 would be omitted if you have a high-end amp comes with an HDMI port.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I will most likely play around with it for a few more days and then buy a surround dac. I presume the majority of them would be compatible? 
thanks again.